# How can I make a padded numpy array using the first/last row/column as the pad?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I am in need of efficiently padding a numpy array on all 4 sides, using the first and last row/column as the padding data.  For example, given the following:

```
A=np.array([[1    2   3   4],
            [5    6   7   8],
            [9   10  11  12]])
```

I am trying to end up with:

```
B=np.array([[1    1    2    3    4    4],
            [1    1    2    3    4    4],
            [5    5    6    7    8    8],
            [9    9   10   11   12   12],
            [9    9   10   11   12   12]])
```

Notice the original array A is located at: B[1:-1,1:-1].  I assume I could pad in one direction first (horizontal or vertical) than the other, to get the duplicated corner values.  However, my vectorization/numpification is failing me.  (Note: the array I am doing this with is quite large, and i need to perform this option many times, so doing it efficiently is key- I can do it with a loop, but it is quite slow).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [`np.pad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html), you can specify the width of padding and the padding mode to apply to an array. For your example array, the `edge` padding mode gives the desired result:

```
>>> np.pad(A, 1, 'edge')
array([[ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  4],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  4],
       [ 5,  5,  6,  7,  8,  8],
       [ 9,  9, 10, 11, 12, 12],
       [ 9,  9, 10, 11, 12, 12]])
```

Comment: Wow, that is convenient.  I hadn't seen it as I was running numpy 1.6, and .pad wasn't added until 1.7.  Updating now.  Edit- and.. worked like a charm.

Comment: Digging into the `np.pad` code shows that it uses 2 concatenates for each dimension - a `_preappend` and an `_append`.